# SQL - Conditional return of joined results

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: Items and Prices with a common item ID key. The relationship is one:many, so one Item can have many Prices.

The price table has these columns:
`itemID`
`priceType`
`price`

What I want to do is select an item by one of its other columns, join to the price table via item ID, and pull prices according to some criteria like this:

```
-if PriceType='primary' then price
-if PriceType='alternate' then price (no primary price is set)
-if PriceType='other' then price (no primary or alternate price is set)
```

Basically, if primary price is not defined, grab the secondary price and so on. I only want one row returned regardless of how many PriceTypes there are and I want to specify the order in which that single item would be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, first thing that comes to mind is an ugly solution containing subqueries so I'd try to avoid that. Using multiple `LEFT JOIN`s of `price` table could do the trick as well, something like this:

```
SELECT item.*, coalesce(pp.price, ap.price, op.price) as price
FROM item
  LEFT JOIN price pp ON pp.itemId = item.itemId AND pp.priceType = 'primary'
  LEFT JOIN price ap ON ap.itemId = item.itemId AND ap.priceType = 'alternate'
  LEFT JOIN price op ON op.itemId = item.itemId AND op.priceType = 'other';
```

The alternative I was first thinking of would be something like

```
SELECT item.*, p.price
FROM item
  INNER JOIN price p ON p.itemId = item.itemId
WHERE p.priceType = 'primary' 
  OR (p.priceType = 'alternate' AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM price p2 WHERE p2.itemId = item.itemId AND p2.priceType = 'primary'))
  OR (p.priceType = 'other' AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM price p2 WHERE p2.itemId = item.itemId AND p2.priceType IN ('primary', 'alternate')))
```

Which is uglier and I believe would perform worse than the 1st example.